# Collapse git commits after push upstream (github)?

Tags: git, github, rebase

I made a bunch of commits on a forked repo locally and when they were done I pushed them upstream (github).  I mistakenly thought I'd have an opportunity to collapse the commits when I pushed but didn't, it pushed (I'm using TortoiseGit).

Is there any way to collapse the commits to one now that they're on GitHub?  I experimented with what it looks like when creating a pull request and in that process it still lists all of the commits with no option to collapse them or provide a single over-all comment.

If no option, is it an option to abandon my fork entirely, re-fork and then re-commit as a single commit and then do a pull request?

The repo I'm referring to is: https://github.com/samuelneff/DefinitelyTyped

I read the warning, "**[Do not rebase commits that you have pushed to a public repository](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing)**" so I'm looking for other options.  Thanks!

Comment: Commits like diamonds are forever. A rebase is actually just making new commits and moving the branch pointer is a non-safe way. As it's your own fork, and you're the only developer on this branch, you should be safe rebasing and force pushing. (in spite of the do not rebase warning).

Comment: You may want to checkout a new branch and rebase master onto that one before submitting the pull request. That way you preserve your commit history, but your pull request will only show 1 commit. Also, don't forget to pull upstream master into your master first, and resolve any merge conflicts :)

Comment: @thgaskell, thanks for the recommendations.  I don't have to worry about merge conflicts though since I added a new definition.  It should be all adding two files.  I did add .gitignore entries but that file hasn't been modified by anybody else since.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to abandon your fork to accomplish what you want.

The only danger of rewriting history comes when that history is being committed to by other people, which you can check [in the network data on GitHub](https://github.com/samuelneff/DefinitelyTyped/network). No one has made commits based on your commits, so you're fine.

- Add the repository that you forked to your remotes: `git remote add <name> <repo url>`

  - In your case: `git remote add borisyankov https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped.git`
- `git rebase <upstream>/master`, where `upstream` is the remote that you named above.
- `git push --force origin master` to force update your `master` branch.

`origin master` isn't needed for pushing if your local `master` is already tracking `origin/master`, which you can check with `git branch -vv` (the tracking branch is in `[ ]`)

> `* master <HEAD commit hash> [origin/master] <HEAD commit message>`

To play it safe, you could do all the above from a new branch off `master` (you won't need to `--force` the push), push it to GitHub, open a pull-request to have a look, then when you feel safe run the steps on `master`.

*Experience*: I often rewrite history on my own projects when I know no one else is using my commits. I no longer fear the `rebase`.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  `git rebase borisyankov/master` gave errors "*fatal: Needed a single revision*" and "*invalid upstream borisyankov/master*".  `git rebase origin/master` gives "*Current branch master is up to date*"

Comment: @SamuelNeff Ah, sorry, I forgot to mention how to add the forked repository as a remote. I've edited my answer to include that. In short, run `git remote add borisyankov https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped.git`

Comment: Cool, thanks.  I'm not used to being a noob again.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: No worries =) I'm always learning, even when it comes to Git!

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely need to combine the commits, `git rebase` followed by `git push --force` is your only option.  Since this looks like a single fork off of the repo, doing a rebase is not as bad of a thing.  As long as you are the only one pushing/pulling from the repo, it is relatively safe.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good question. I assume when I put in a pull request for a new definition file the others would much rather see a single commit with "Added new definition file for MySQL" rather than a ton of commits.  Does it matter?

Comment: @SamuelNeff A single, squashed commit of several only matters if that's what the maintainer wants. Otherwise, save yourself the hassle and don't worry about it =)